# Find the matrix products.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ square matrix of order $n$ consider $E_{ij}$ to be a matrix with $1$ at the $i-j$ entry and $0$ elsewhere. What is $AE_{ij}, E_{ij}A$ and $E_{ij}AE_{st}?$

If we let $A=(a_{ij})$ and $E=(e_{xy})$ and $C=(c_{pq})$ where $C$ is the resultant matrix.

When $C=AE_{ij}$ then $c_{pq}=a_{pi}\delta_{qj}$

When $C=E_{ij}A$ then $c_{pq}=\delta_{pi}a_{jq}.$

When $C=E_{ij}AE_{st}=\delta_{pi}a_{js}\delta_{qt}.$

Are these expressions correct?

Comment: I think your equations are ill defined because you have indices on one side but not on the other, is there some sort of sum going on or should C have indices also

Comment: But the sum sort of annihilates because many entries are zero, right?

Comment: So we initially write the sum and then we observe that most it will be zero unless a certain index is achieved. That's how I did the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are correct indeed:

in the first case only the ith column of A survive as jth column in C

in the second case only the jth row of A survive as ith row in C

in the third case only the (j,s) element of A survive as (i,t) element in C